# Issue while querying for singing up the user "this authentication method is unsupported"

Tags: android, parse-platform

i did the migration process for using the parse platform locally. i have deployed the [**parse-server-example**](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) on my localhost and hosted the DB on mongolab. First step is i am trying to register the user using the local parse server and on the DB instance hosted on mongolab.

This is the [**index.js**](https://gist.github.com/KunalKathrotia/26d48ac0cef445faa64b) of locally deployed parse server, and the following is the code snippet for android.

```
// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
// Add your initialization code here
//Parse.initialize(this);
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("my app id")
        .clientKey("my client key")
        .server("http://10.12.41.250:1337/parse/")   // '/' important after 'parse'
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new ParseStethoInterceptor())
        .build());
....
....

final ParseUser parseUser = new ParseUser();
parseUser.setUsername(edtUsername.getText().toString());
parseUser.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
parseUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "You are now registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Success
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                //Failure
            }
        }
    });
```

Upon executing this i am getting ParseRequestException with error message "this authentication method is unsupported", now i don't know what is it about and only thing that i found so far is [*This*](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/413).

The following is the detail of network interceptor.

[image: error]

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why but after 4 days or so of trying, it's working surprisingly today. All i did was just deleted the database from mongolab and created a new DB and did the migration process again. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, That was an issue and it's [**Fixed**](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/413) now.